# Cannot start network manager gui

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have recently ordered a wifi dongle and need to use network manager to connect to the network, but for some reason I just can't start it. I am using Ubunutu 15.04 Vivid.
`sudo start network-manager` returns the following error:

`start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

Running `network-manager` by itself (with or without `sudo`) returns:

`network-manager: command not found`

It is also not in the menu.
I have upgraded `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` and the problem has persisted.
If there is another way to show available networks and connect to one with all normal features, this will work for me too.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru Oops! Sorry! 15.04 Vivid

Comment: Try `systemctl start NetworkManager.service` instead.

Comment: Will this start the service, or the gui? I am trying to start the gui.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu 15.04, try using

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: Thanks. It has been so long, I am now running 15.10 and using a different wifi dongle. However, if your answer still allows me to start `network-manager` I will still mark it as correct.